# Matching an integer between the brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am given bunch of strings in the following format:

```
ASDF [         6]

ZXC[1]

OtPasd[ 4 ]

asdffa[   7]
```

I need to retrieve the integer between the brackets on strings that are valid. The strings are valid as long as:

1. Only white spaces are present in between the brackets. I.E: "ZXCV[ a2]" is not valid
2. All brackets are properly closed. I.E: "qwr[2" is not valid
3. All strings have a single opening/closing bracket only. I.E: "zxcf[4]]]" is not valid

I would preferably like to avoid Regex as I am getting a large number of strings so something computationally unintensive would be preferable.

What is the cleanest and **fastest** way to validate and retrieve the integer?

Edit: I decided to use Regex.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried. I can appreciate that it's difficult to learn, but you should at least be trying something and showing.

Comment: why do you discard the idea of regex? So far I see it is the most simple way to get your numbers out and it probably will be as fast as any other solution. Premature optimisation is a root of all evil!

Comment: Using a combination of `String.IndexOf`, `String.Trim`, and `Int.TryParse` seems likely. However, I think you should reconsider using Regexes, they might not be as expensive as you first believe.

Comment: @trailmax Amen to that! Also, a regex will probably turn out more robust than manual splitting, trimming, etc.

Comment: Use a regex, THEN if it's found to be a bottlenect improve the performance.  Write clean working maintainable code, then write fast code.  And let's not forget, in C#, a Regex can be **COMPILED**

Comment: I don't really mind using Regex. I would've just liked to see any other solution than Regex provided that it is clean and feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion the cleanest solution is to use regexes. But instead of guessing if it is computationally intensive I would rather benchmark it. Here's the code.

```
const int Count = 10000000;
const string testString = "<whatever>";

// Solution No. 1: use Regex.Match()    
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(@"\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]$", testString);
    if (!match.Success)
        continue;
    var number = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

// Solution No. 2: use IndexOf() and Substring() shenanigans
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    var lb = testString.IndexOf('[');
    var rb = testString.LastIndexOf(']');
    if (lb < 0 || rb != testString.Length - 1)
        continue;
    var str = testString.Substring(lb + 1, rb - lb - 1);
    int number;
    if (!int.TryParse(str, out number))
        continue;
    // use the number
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

And here are the results:

```
Solution  |  testString  |   Time (ms)  | Comment
----------|--------------|--------------|-----------------------
     1    | abc [      ] |    4476      | Invalid input string
     2    | abc [      ] |    6594      | Invalid input string
     1    | abc[1234]    |    4446      | Valid input string
     2    | abc[1234]    |    6290      | Valid input string
```

As you can see, not only the regex solution is shorter and cleaner, it is actually faster. And if you play with different input strings you will notice that the longer your input string is, the larger the gap between the first and the second solutions.

Comment: @Igor Korkhov, it could be faster by storing the compiled Regex. `var regex = new Regex(@"\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]$", RegexOptions.Compiled );`

Comment: @CaffGeek: not really, 'cos the *static* `Regex.Match()` caches last 10 or so compiled regexes automatically.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov, I noticed a difference, but maybe it was the cost of creating the new regex object, not the regex compilation that saved time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]$
```

Comment: Matches the brackets as well. I just want the integer inside the bracket. I.E: asdf [       3    ] gives you [          3   ] back

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?m)(?!<=\[)(\[\s*)(\d+)(\s*\])(?!\])`
your integer in match group

Comment: Matches the brackets as well. I just want the integer inside the bracket. I.E: asdf [       3    ] gives you [          3   ] back

Comment: It's not. MatchCollection a = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?m)(?!<=\[)(\[\s*)(\d+)(\s*\])(?!\])"); gives you a single item back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using Regex... Would using IndexOf/LastIndexOf and then parsing the remaining string be suitable for what you need?

Answer (score 0):

To get the int in between the brackets you can also try this way:

```
string tmpString = "ASDF [         6]";
int start = tmpString.IndexOf('[') + 1;
int length = tmpString.IndexOf(']') - start;
string subString = tmpString.Substring(start, length);
int tempInt;
if(Int.TryParse(subString, out tempInt))
return tempInt;
```

Comment: good idea, but need a bit more work/validation on cases like  "aasdf[[[5]]][]". But let's leave some work to do for l46kok -)

Comment: Indeed, we don't need to give him all the code I think :) But when he combines some questions here, he'll get far with his answer