# matching integers in brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching an integer between the brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370794/matching-an-integer-between-the-brackets)

What is the regex for matching an integer between the brackets? For example,

```
"ASDF[ 4 ]"

"ZXCd[6]"

"qwerr   [    77 ]"
```

Strings matched would be "4","6","77"

The problem is, I don't know of any regex that can match the integers AND ignore the white spaces. Any thoughts?

Comment: [titles don't need the tags in them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
(?<=\[\s*)\d+(?=\s*\])
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker thank you for the edit. I missed to read the `white space`

Comment: This works absolutely fine. Wow thanks.